# Open xml runtime requirements

Tags: .net, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am creating a .NET application to manipulate word files using [OpenXml SDK](http://openxmldeveloper.org/).

What are the prequisites (in runtime environment) to use Open Xml? Do i need to install [Open XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) or toolkit on client machine?

Is it possible to just provide the referenced libraries with application, and do away with any open xml installer related dependency?

Answer (score 3):

The **second** download in the link that's referenced in your question contains and installs the DocumentFormat.OpenXml dll. Your visual studio project needs a reference to this dll. You also need .NET 3.5 and above. Then you can get started on using Open XML.

The **first** download contains a link to Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity tool. This tool allows you see how the XML structure of a document looks like. It also helps you to "reverse-engineer" an excel or a word document and thus is highly recommended (though not mandatory.)

Also I would highly recommend going through the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET Core install the `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` from the NuGet package.

Right Click on Packages - > Manage NuGetPackages - > Select - >DocumentFormat.OpenXML

Import the below namespaces

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
```

for reference please go through below link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk